# How does the failure of integral closure of a coordinate ring relate to the cusp/singularity we see in the corresponding variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the affine variety with coordinate ring $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$.

It is clear that the coordinate ring $R$ is not integrally closed since $t=y/x$, an element of the corresponding quotient field, is a root of an integral equation.

What is the geometric intuition relating the failure of $y/x$ to belong to $R$ and the cusp we see on the graph of $y^2-x^2=0$?

Comment: To desingularize the curve, one can [blow up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up) the origin.  Consider the graph $\Gamma$ of the map $f(x,y) = y/x$ defined on $\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$, so $\Gamma$ is a subseteq of $\mathbb{A}^2 \times \mathbb{A}^1$.  The function $y/x$ gives the slopes of the different tangent lines, and since this is the $z$-coordinate in $\Gamma$, it turns the singularity into a point tangent to the $z$-axis.  You can read more in section 7.2 of [Fulton](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf), and I may try to give a full answer later.

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1504/what-is-the-geometric-meaning-of-integral-closure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rational function $y/x$ is regular (i.e., defined) at every point on your curve $C$ other than the origin $P = (0,0)$, but at $P$ it is undefined.  In order to get a function defined at the origin, we can blow up the point $P$, which will resolve the singularity at $P$.

The idea behind blowing up is the following.  At a singular point $P$, there are multiple tangent lines.  So we can replace that single point by several points, one for each tangent line, by adding another coordinate (a copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$) that keeps track of the slope of the tangent line.  When $P = (0,0)$ is the origin, the slope is given by the function $y/x$, so our new coordinate $z$ will satisfy $z = y/x$, or $y = xz$ if we clear denominators.  So really the blowup is (the closure of) the graph of the function $y/x$ on $C \setminus P$; see section 7.2 of [Fulton's *Algebraic Curves*](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) for details.

Your example is a bit confusing since the cuspidal cubic $y^2 = x^3$ has just one tangent line ($y = 0$) with multiplicity $2$ at the origin, so let's first consider the nodal cubic $y^2 = x^2(x + 1)$.  Since its homogeneous term of lowest order is $y^2 - x^2 = (y - x)(y + x)$, then the nodal cubic has tangent lines $y = x$ and $y = -x$ at the origin.  The function $y/x$ allows us to distinguish between the two branches of the curve.  For points along the branch approximated by $y = x$ we have $y/x \approx 1$, and for those on the other branch, we will have $y/x \approx -1$.

So we will "pull apart" these branches by making a curve in $\mathbb{A}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ whose $z$-coordinate is $y/x$.  To find the equations for the blowup $\newcommand{\wt}{\widetilde} \wt{C}$, we simply substitute $y = xz$ in to the equations for $C$:
\begin{align*}
x^2(x+1) &= y^2 = x^2 z^2 \implies 0 = x^2(z^2 - (x+1)) = 0
\end{align*}
The factor of $x^2$ corresponds to the extra factor of $\mathbb{P}^1$ we introduced, while the other factor gives us the relation $x = z^2 - 1$.  Since $y = xz$, we find the parametric curve
$$
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\wt{C} = \{(z^2 - 1, z(z^2 - 1), z) : z \in \C\} \, .
$$
Below is the plot (made in [*SageMath*](http://www.sagemath.org/)) of the original curve, the blowup, and the points where it intersects the added copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

$\hspace{3cm}$ [image]

We can do the same thing in the case of the cuspidal cubic, obtaining the parametric curve
$$
\wt{C} = \{(z^2 , z^3, z) : z \in \C\}
$$
as shown in Zach Teitler's answer.

$\hspace{3cm}$ [image]

It's kind of hard to see what's going on from these still images, so it might be more illuminating to play with the interactive plots (made with [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)) yourself: [nodal cubic](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyNzkELwiAUwPH7YN9B1mHaXEzHjn2SqHBOmsxU9FXQp8-tS9CIDsJ7h__vuUHWDcIgeeu1zLO7CLiEkuSZZ2iPvAjiqiBoefbGAcZw4jWjsH0PhDaEIgy0ZruOppc2GLWcrIox5Xx2-D8OfDnSGRdSWlyCUrZYgds1uKHNL6w3Qk7FXMPseKct4MNSzd9Ay8TI8SMJakjXo36qtLEutXF0D-xZ5Xnl2ypJ5AW8slqc&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), [cuspidal cubic](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9zUEKwjAQBdB9oXcIddGERklSuvQkYiVNgw3GJiSjgqd36kqwdDEwH-b92RHzyNGN2uMyOFMWT51oDTUriyjJkUSd9N1CcuYSfQBKoVcc-pYLxgkFvpeHjuNggsmZ22xzRqYWr7Y8_HkTfEhIqmuydq5WCtu1QsHFVtngtblVi4alJwY3Az19lWDnn8NkR_yZ3dtikh2KPIUXjbKJqoltg559AG89Vts=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==).

The code for these plots is below.

```
# nodal cubic
var('t')
p1 = parametric_plot((t^2-1,t*(t^2-1),0), (t,-1.5,1.5), thickness = 2)
p2 = parametric_plot((t^2-1,t*(t^2-1),t), (t,-1.5,1.5), color = "green", thickness = 2)
p3 = parametric_plot((0,0,t), (t,-1.5,1.5), color = "black")
pts = point([(0,0,-1), (0,0,1)], color = "red", size = 5)
show(p1+p2+p3+pts)
```

```
# cuspidal cubic
var('t')
p1 = parametric_plot((t^2,t^3,0), (t,-1.5,1.5), thickness = 2)
p2 = parametric_plot((t^2,t^3,t), (t,-1.5,1.5), color = "green", thickness = 2)
p3 = parametric_plot((0,0,t), (t,-1.5,1.5), color = "black")
pts = point([(0,0,0)], color = "red", size = 5)
show(p1+p2+p3+pts)
```

[This paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2003-40-03/S0273-0979-03-00982-0/S0273-0979-03-00982-0.pdf) and [this webpage](https://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/graph/nodal.html) have some great images, too.

Answer (score 4):

Let $R' = R[y/x]$. We can think of $R \subset R' \subset \operatorname{Frac}(R)$, the field of fractions of $R$.

I claim that $R' \cong \mathbb{C}[t]$. Write $t = y/x \in R'$. In $R'$, $xt=y$, so $x^2 t^2 = y^2 = x^3$. Since $R'$ is an integral domain, $t^2 = x$. And then $t^3 = y$. So (with some hand-waving) $R' = \mathbb{C}[x,y,t]/(y^2-x^3) \cong \mathbb{C}[x,y,t]/(t^2-x,t^3-y) \cong \mathbb{C}[t]$.

If you are familiar with prime spectra of rings, the inclusion $R \subset R'$ gives a map $\operatorname{Spec} R' \to \operatorname{Spec} R$.

If you would rather work with affine varieties, $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(y^2-x^3)$ means $\operatorname{Spec}(R) = V(y^2-x^3)$. What about $R'$? Here $\operatorname{Spec}(R') = V(t^2-x,t^3-y) \subset \mathbb{C}^3$. This is a smooth (nonsingular) curve, parametrized by $t \mapsto (t^2,t^3,t)=(x,y,t)$.

The projection $(x,y,t) \mapsto (x,y)$ gives a map of curves $V(t^2-x,t^3-y) \to V(y^2-x^3)$.

The projection $(x,y,t) \mapsto (x,y)$ has a critical point when the tangent line of the curve is "vertical", i.e., in the kernel of the projection to the $xy$-plane. The derivative of the parametrization is $(2t,3t^2,1)$, which is equal to $(0,0,1)$ when $t=0$. So $t=0$ (or $(x,y,t) = (0,0,0)$) is a critical point of the projection from this curve to the $xy$-plane, and $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is a critical value.